# Trying to add a winforms control added to form in design time programmatically from a custom class

Tags: c#, winforms

Ok so I added a contextmenustrip to form1 in a winforms app. I have a standard class elsewhere that takes a treenode as a parameter and does things to it. One of the things I would like to do is set the context menu. The context menu was added to the form manually at design time.

I have tried things like:

```
public static void MethodThatAddsAContextMenu(TreeNode node)
{
    node.ContextMenuStrip = Application.OpenForms[0].Controls["myContextMenu"] as ContextMenuStrip;
}
```

And what seems like a million subtle and not so subtle variations. My code doesn't find the control. Although it looks like the context menu isn't actually part of the forms control collection when I drill in via my watch list.

Any help appreciated. Also I did this on my iPad, looks like its formatted ok but apologies if not.

Thanks in advance.

Ok, Boo as per your suggestion probably easier to just post the code:

```
private static TreeNode CreateSecurityNode(Security Sec)
{
    TreeNode sn = new TreeNode(Sec.SecurityName);
    sn.Tag = Sec;
    sn.ContextMenuStrip = Application.OpenForms[0].Container.Components["securityContext"] as ContextMenuStrip;
}
```

Container returns `null`.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: My question is how do I set the nodes' ContextMenustrip to the strip that was added to the form manually at design time from my custom class, programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

ContextMenuStrip would not be part of the `Form.Controls` collection.  It is a component, not a control.

I would try passing in the ContextMenuStrip with the TreeNode.

Alternatively you could have your class construct and attach a context menu at runtime.

Also-

You could populate a `List<ContextMenuStrip>` with all your context menus (or a `Dictionary<ContextMenuStrip>`) and expose that as a property of the form:

```
public List<ContextMenuStrip> contextMenus {get;set;}

// // form load event, possibly
this.contextMenus.Add(myContextMenu);
```

Comment: Thanks, Boo. I tried the components like this:
            sn.ContextMenuStrip = Application.OpenForms[0].Container.Components["securityContext"] as ContextMenuStrip; which did not work. Still could not find the context menu strip. I would -pass the ContextMenuStrip with th enode but they are coming from two seperate places. The node is created programatically elsewhere. I would create the ContextMenuSTrip with the node also but its wired in fairly heavily in the page.

Comment: You should edit your original question and provide the modified code there.